# Error :Ensure that the device is developer unlocked. Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030118

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I got this message :-Error : DEP0200 : Ensure that the device is developer unlocked. For details on developer unlock, visit  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317976 : Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030118

But i have already registered it

[image]

My Error:- Error : DEP0200 : Ensure that the device is developer unlocked. For details on developer unlock, visit  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317976 : Exception from HRESULT: 0x81030118

my output window :-

[image]

i don't know how to handle this .....

operating system :- windows 8.1

phone operating system :- windows 8.1

i think this is the problem :-

[image]

when I open the windows 8.1 registration 
 I got this :-

[image]

but in windows phone developer

[image]

Comment: This issue is reported to Microsoft under visual studio and .Net framework issue at this https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1233642/erro-dep0200-ensure-that-the-device-is-developer-unlocked. Meanwhile try to test on another phone or another machine.

Comment: @Nishi plz check the edited part .....

Comment: images are not loaded at my end :( so cant understand whats happening.

Comment: I too have Wp8.1 and WP registration tool for WP and WP8.1 both. For me it shows my phone registered for both. If I unregister from any one, it shows my phone developer locked for both, So you try to register your phone with WP registration tool as well and then try.

Comment: i don't know what happens with it but today it works..... those who have the same problem plz restart your system ......... it might work ...  @Nishi thanks for your support

Comment: it stopped working again ........ don't know what to do... it is frustrating for me  can any one help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Rename yuor Phone in File Explorer.
I helped

Comment: Sorry, but my tongue is Russian so use Google translator.

I had the same problem. In my second Developer phone registration is steamed and I could not re-register.
In the vastness of MSDN, I saw an indication that the names must be unique phone and that the phone name can be changed.Unfortunately add image does not allow small reputation.

So I write the words.
- Open the "My Computer"
- Find the connected phone
- Click on the right mouse button and select Rename
- Enter a new name for the phone
- You try to register the phone again

Comment: hi @roman thanks for your answer but my problem is solved ...... i was using windows 10 and windows 8.1 ...... this type of conflict occurred by windows 10 .... i don't know reason behind this but it does......   for those who have the same problem plz reset your phone and then register it with windows 8.1.... now my problem is solved :) .... avoid using windows 10 for phone development.